# Angular 2 / Provide config for parent service

Tags: angular

This is how I provide a config for my DataService

```
providers: [
     {provide: DataServiceConfig, useValue: config }, DataService
]
```

That makes it easy to inject the config into my DataService constructor. But that only works if DataService and the providers are part of the same module. That makes sense because the config provider must be available.

But how can I solve it if DataService is part of the **parent module**? It won't work this way because I can't inject config into DataService because config isn't available unless I have loaded the child module. Any ideas on that?

Comment: This works fine if the child module is not lazy loaded. If it is lazy loaded it needs to implement `forRoot()` and then `forRoot()` needs to be imported in the `AppModule` or a module imported into the `AppModule`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes, it is lazyloaded. So you say that I need to implement forRoot into my DataModule which is the child module and then import DataModule.forRoot() in my AppModule. Am I right? Does this not contrast lazyloading if I import the module anyway?

Comment: No `forRoot()` is a static method and doesn't import the whole module, only the providers you add there. So yes, the service will be included in the initial download, but the rest of the module won't.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thank you for making that clear. But I've got one last problem. I have not only one DataModule but three different ones. For demonstration purposes call them DataModule1, DataModule2, DataModule3. So there are three possibilities how the config looks like. It actually depends on which one get's lazyloaded. So if I import all three providers how do I know which one is the right provider.

Comment: Sorry, but I somehow lost track what is in parent and what in child and what depends on what. Can you add the code to demonstrate what you try to accomplish?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've created a plunkr. That's exactly what I have on my local system although the plunkr goes into Maximum call stack error, when I open a route. So I have this service that holds a random config param. The Layout Component depends on this service. When I call data1 or data2, I want to change the config string in service. https://plnkr.co/edit/kVAJ0owsCZRbiW8DtHMi

Comment: The Plunker seems not to contain all the services you mentioned.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Sure, it is only one service.

Comment: Then I don't understand "I have not only one DataModule but three different ones. For demonstration purposes call them DataModule1, DataModule2, DataModule3. So there are three possibilities how the config looks like." and also not "DataService is part of the parent module"

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I broke down the example on plunkr to two DataModules called DataOneModule and DataTwoModule. So here two possibilities to set the config. The actual service that needs to be configured is called Service.

Comment: "The actual services that needs to be configured" configured with what?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I also broke this down to a simple String public config = "some configuration";  I updated the plunkr and put a string into each of the DataModules that need to replace the config in the Service.

Comment: If you provide `Service` in a `@NgModule()` (non-lazy loaded) then there is only a single instance, and a single instance can't be configured with different configurations. I'm just not able to understand what you try to accomplish.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer To make it more understandable. Service in my case is a MenuService that holds the MenuItems for the application. The thing is that the menu depends on the lazyloaded ChildModules. So each of the ChildModules has a hard coded configuration for the menu. If the ChildModule loads it should pass the right configuration to the Parent MenuService. Does this make it more clear?

Comment: I think I understand it now. The config service provided in the lazy loaded child modules, can inject the `MenuService` and call a method on it (for example in its constructor).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thank you for your patience. Yes that's an option but that means that I need to create a config Service. At the moment I just have a config constant in my child module. Can I inject MenuService directly into my module and call a function on it?

Comment: I think so. I haven't tried but you should be able to create a constructor in the `ChildModule` class and inject a service.

Comment: Okay, I will try that. Thank you @GünterZöchbauer.